# Arduino's Resolution with Multiple Analog Inputs

Tags: arduino, adc, resolution

Resolution of an analog to digital conversion means the ratio between the maximum value of the measured signal to the number of data point that it can resolve(0-1023). So for Arduino(10-bit) my resolution is 5V/1024=4.88mV. Now I wonder if this value changes when I read voltage from multiple analog inputs. For example if I read analog values from 5 inputs, is this means that my resolution decreases to 5*5V/1024=24mV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, each input is multiplexed into a single 10 bit ADC. Regardless of how many analog inputs you read from, the resolution is 10 bits. In the future, carefully read documentation and all will become clear!

Answer (score 6):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f77Wn3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Typical 8-channel micro ADC input. Channel selector logic not shown.*

The ADC (analog-digital converter) is preceded by a multiplexed input selector. There is only one ADC in the chip.

- All analog inputs share the one ADC.
- Only one input pin can be connected to the ADC at any time.
- Since all channels use the same ADC any comparison between the various inputs will share the same input offset errors and non-linearity. This will help minimise comparison errors.
- Note that there is generally some input resistance and capacitance and the data sheet will normally recommend that you select a channel, wait long enough for the capacitor value to stabilise (5 x RC would give > 99%) and then trigger the ADC. This is one of the factors which limits the maximum ADC scan rate.
- Since you can't sample two inputs simultaneously it is not possible to compare two inputs at *exactly* the same instant. There will be a small delay between the readings.